# PHPUnit and Magento Bootstrap Fatal error: Uncaught CredisException

Tags: redis, phpunit, magento-1.9, php-7.2

I have a problem with **Magento 1.9** and **PHPUNit 7.4**. PHP version is **7.2**.

Below the tree. `http` is the folder of `Magento`.

```
root/
├── http/
│   └── app
├── php-unit -> (with composer)
├── test/
│   └── unit/
│       ├── bootstrap.php
│       └── testsuite/
│           └── module
└── phpunit.xml
```

Below XML source file.

```
<!-- phpunit.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/|version|/phpunit.xsd"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="tests/unit/bootstrap.php"
    cacheTokens="true"
    backupGlobals="true"
    forceCoversAnnotation="false"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    stopOnRisky="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader"
    timeoutForSmallTests="1"
    timeoutForMediumTests="10"
    timeoutForLargeTests="60"
    colors="true"
    verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test Suite">
            <directory>tests/unit/testsuite/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">http/app/code/local/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>http/app/Mage.php</file>
                <directory suffix=".php">http/app/code/core</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">http/app/code/local/Credis</directory>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">http/app/design</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">http/lib/Varien</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">http/lib/Zend</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">http/lib/Magento</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Below `bootstrap.php`.

```
//bootstrap.php
class Bootstrap {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Loading Magento\n";

        # ABSOLUTE PATH SERVER
        require_once( getcwd().'/http/app/Mage.php' );
        echo "require_once Mage\n";

        Mage::app(); <--- Error
        echo "start Mage::app()\n";
```

The error message, finally:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CredisException: Connection to Redis redis:6379 failed after 2 failures.
Last Error : (0) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /myfolder/http/app/code/local/Credis/Client.php:475
```

Comment: Resolved,
I leave my solution, so maybe it can also be useful to others.
problem due to the virtualization of containers.

If you run PHPUnit from the Linux CLI, where above there is docker installed.
Magento can not reach Docker's containers.
If you run from the CLI of a container, everything works.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it as the solution =)